# react-native JSApplicationIllegalArgumentException: Animated node with tag [#] does not exists

Tags: react-native

I'm using react-native 0.70.

On android 12, I got this error on release build.

```
com.facebook.react.bridge.JSApplicationIllegalArgumentException: connectAnimatedNodes: Animated node with tag (child) [59746] does not exist
at com.facebook.react.animated.NativeAnimatedNodesManager.connectAnimatedNodes(NativeAnimatedNodesManager.java:369)
at com.facebook.react.animated.NativeAnimatedModule$16.execute(NativeAnimatedModule.java:800)
at com.facebook.react.animated.NativeAnimatedModule$ConcurrentOperationQueue.executeBatch(NativeAnimatedModule.java:191)
at com.facebook.react.animated.NativeAnimatedModule$3.execute(NativeAnimatedModule.java:381)
at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$UIBlockOperation.execute(UIViewOperationQueue.java:579)
at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$1.run(UIViewOperationQueue.java:915)
at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue.flushPendingBatches(UIViewOperationQueue.java:1026)
at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue.access$2600(UIViewOperationQueue.java:47)
at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$DispatchUIFrameCallback.doFrameGuarded(UIViewOperationQueue.java:1086)
```

Any recommendations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is related only to Android 12.

Try to disable `useNativeDriver` only for Android 12.

An example:

```
export const USE_NATIVE_DRIVER = Platform.select({
  ios: true,
  android: Platform.constants?.Release !== '12',
  default: true,
});
```

--

```
Animated.timing(animation, {
  toValue: 1,
  duration: 3000,
  useNativeDriver: USE_NATIVE_DRIVER,
})
```

Comment: what about the other dependency such as react-navigation etc?